# How to write unit test for send email

Tags: email, yii2, codeception

I Have some code for send email message:

```
class Mailer extends Component implements SenderContract
{
    const EVENT_SEND = 'send';

    public function init(){

        $this->on(self::EVENT_SEND, [$this, 'send']);

    }

    public function send(MessageContract $event)
    {
        \Yii::$app->mailer->compose(['html' => 'layouts/html'],
            ['content' => $event->getMessage()])
            ->setFrom([\Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'] => 'theme message'])
            ->setTo($event->getSender())
            ->setSubject('new message')
            ->send();
    }
}
```

I use codeception unit test. How I can do mock for send() method ?

Comment: See the unit test for ContactForm in [Basic App Template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/tests/unit/models/ContactFormTest.php) and [Advanced App Template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/tests/unit/models/ContactFormTest.php).

Comment: @bizley Thanks I will try